# Django's loaddata is not recognizing my manytomanyfield

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to load a model that has a `ManyToManyField`, but when I do, I don't think that Django is recognizing it in the way that my data is formatted.

Here is my JSON code:

```
[ 
{
"pk": 1, 
"model": "myapp.unipart", 
"fields": {
  "last_updated": "2012-06-12 16:27:01", 
  "description": "My description", 
  "coverart": "", 
  "url": "http://sjjdd.pdf", 
  "source": "sdfsdf", 
  "part": "sfsdfsd", 
  "shortdesc": "ssds3", 
  "dsfd": [], 
  "category_id": [1,2,3,4,5,10,11], 
  "uid": 123, 
  "manufacturer": "dsfsd"
}
  }
]
```

The field that is causing the problem is `category_id`. I had to manually enter those values because dumpdata was leaving `category_id` blank. So not sure if that has anything to do with it or not.

I know this is not a lot of data to go on but I'm stumped. Is the way I entered the key values in `category_id` correct?

Any other ideas of how I can either dump the field or do some debugging to find out why it's not reading this properly?

By the way, I verified that all of the values in category_id do indeed exist in the category table that it maps to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the values I was storing as `category_id`'s were not the primary keys for the `Category` table, so as a result Django could not find any corresponding entries in the table. I had integers in there -- which is why it was confusing, but they were referring to another field in the table.

So if this is also happening to you, make sure to verify that you're mapping to the primary key id of the table that your many-to-many table links to!